# Pattern matching with lazy list

Tags: list, pattern-matching, ocaml, lazy-evaluation

I have this type for a lazy list:

```
type 'a lazyList = Cons of 'a * (unit -> 'a lazyList)
```

I wrote a function that returns the first n elements from such a list:

```
let rec take n l = 
  if (n = 0) then [] 
  else 
    match l with h :: t -> h :: take (n - 1) (t ())
```

So the idea is that I take this first element of the lazy list and then evaluate the list by calling `()` on it.

But instead I have to write it like this:

```
let rec take n l = 
  if (n = 0) then [] 
  else 
    match l with Cons ((h, t)) -> h :: take (n - 1) (t ())
```

Why do I first have to wrap it with `Cons`?

Comment: Because that's how you've defined the type. A better question would be why you've defined the type that way. Try removing `Cons of` from the type definition and see what happens.

Comment: To put this another way, your type definition says that every value of type `'a lazylist` has the form `Cons (...)`. So that's what you have to match against. In addition to what @glennsl says, I wonder what is the purpose of your `uint` parameter. What should you pass for this when the list is infinite?

Comment: Please note that `let rec take n l = if n = 0 then [] else match l with h::t ->` can be written as: `let rec take n (h::t) = if n = 0 then [] else ` though this is non-exhaustive pattern matching either way.

Comment: To put this yet another way, `Cons` and `(::)` are distinct constructor names. The latter is not syntactic sugar for the former. The standard list datatype uses `(::)` and your lazylist datatype uses `Cons`. [@JeffreyScofield: `uint` appeared to be a typo for `unit`.]